# try except not catching exception

Tags: python-2.7, scipy

I have a pieced of numerical code that can fail for various reasons, and I would like to replace the output value with numpy.NAN when it does so things keep moving along. I tried to wrap the call to brentq in a try: except: statement, but it still crashed my code on the same exception.

```py
def someotherfunction(stuff):
    self.energy2ph = lambda e: self.brentq_fails_to_NAN(ph2offset_energy, 0., max_ph, args=(e,))    
def brentq_fails_to_NAN(self, *args):
    ''' this simply calls scipy.optimize.brentq with the exact same arguments, 
    but in the case of an error it returns numpy.NAN instead of throwing an exception '''
    try:
        return scipy.optimize.brentq(*args)
    except:
        print 'returning numpy.NAN instead of throwing an exception for energy2ph'
        return numpy.NAN
```

I get a traceback with an exception that goes back to my try statement. My understanding is that is should run the code under the except: statement in that case

```py
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mass/calibration/energy_calibration.pyc in name2ph(self, name)
    257 
    258     def brentq_fails_to_NAN(self, *args):
--> 259         try:
    260             return scipy.optimize.brentq(*args)
    261         except:

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mass/calibration/energy_calibration.pyc in <lambda>(e)
    252         max_ph = 1.3*self._ph[-1]
    253         ph2offset_energy = lambda ph, eoffset: self.ph2energy(ph)-eoffset
--> 254 #        self.energy2ph = lambda e: scipy.optimize.brentq(ph2offset_energy, 0., max_ph, args=(e,))
    255         self.energy2ph = lambda e: self.brentq_fails_to_NAN(ph2offset_energy, 0., max_ph, args=(e,))
    256 

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/zeros.pyc in brentq(f, a, b, args, xtol, rtol, maxiter, full_output, disp)
    387     if type(args) != type(()) :
    388         args = (args,)
--> 389     r = _zeros._brentq(f,a,b,xtol,maxiter,args,full_output,disp)
    390     return results_c(full_output, r)
    391 

ValueError: f(a) and f(b) must have different signs
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some exception is being swallowed in this case , please try this

```
except Exception:
        print 'returning numpy.NAN instead of throwing an exception for energy2ph'
        return numpy.NAN
```